# Why `newtype` does not work with this pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, newtype

I tried the following code by implementing data as `Enum`.
And, I have a question just replacing `Enum` by `newtype`.

And here is my test code.

```hs
newtype Fruit = Fruit Int deriving (Eq)

apple = Fruit 0
banana = Fruit 1
grape = Fruit 2
orange = Fruit 3

instance Show Fruit where
  show apple = "Apple"
  show banana = "Banana"
  show grape = "Grape"
  show orange = "Orange"
  show _ = "Fruit"

test =
  map show [apple, banana, grape, orange, (Fruit 5)]
```

I expected that evaluated `test` will be `["Apple","Banana","Grape","Orange","Fruit"]`, but it is `["Apple","Apple","Apple","Apple","Apple"]`

I assume that it variable may not work well with pattern matching, but I tried one more time by `case`, like:

```hs
-- Fails: everything is "Apple"
instance Show Fruit where
  show g = case g of
    apple -> "Apple"
    banana -> "Banana"
    grape -> "Grape"
    orange -> "Orange"
    _ -> "Fruit"
```

To confirm my temporary, I tried again with the next code.

```hs
-- Fails: Works only for apple/banana. Variable does not work!
instance Show Fruit where
  show (Fruit 0) = "Apple"
  show (Fruit 1) = "Banana"
  show grape = "Grape"
  show orange = "Orange"
  show _ = "Fruit"
```

And I could get `["Apple","Banana","Grape","Grape","Grape"]`

Well, I can write code to implement with `Enum`, but I just want to understand why the codes do not work that I supposed?

Comment: Should you use `data` instead of `newtype` ?

Comment: Side note: `show grape` and `show orange` are the equivalent to `show _` and therefore overlapping patterns. The compiler will not match orange with it's above definition but treat it as a local identifier.

Comment: If you only use statically defined fruits, you should really use a sum type to represent your data instead of using a wrapper around `Int`. For example: `data Fruit = Apple | Banana | Grape | Orange deriving Eq`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code

```
instance Show Fruit where
  show apple = "Apple"
  show banana = "Banana"
  show grape = "Grape"
  show orange = "Orange"
  show _ = "Fruit"
```

is equivalent to

```
instance Show Fruit where
  show x = "Apple"
  show y = "Banana"
  show z = "Grape"
  show w = "Orange"
  show _ = "Fruit"
```

since it declares new variables named `apple, ...` which shadow the globally defined ones, without being related to those in any way.

Try instead

```
instance Show Fruit where
  show x | x == apple = "Apple"
         | x == banana = "Banana"
         | x == grape = "Grape"
         | x == orange = "Orange"
         | otherwise = "Fruit"
```

The thumb rule to remember is: in a pattern, all the variables are local variables *defined* by the pattern.

I'd recommend to turn on warnings with `-Wall`, since that would have pointed out the shadowing of global variables by local ones.

Comment: Thanks, I really forget about it! However, then why the implement that I used case could not work well?

Comment: @QuietJoon `case` is not different from multiple equations. `case` also uses patterns, which declare new local variables... same issue.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to what you seem to be trying to do is to use [PatternSynonyms](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-03-pattern-synonyms.html).